# Is it possible to write an SQL query that does a 'find and replace' with two tables?

Tags: sql, database, datatable, derby

### Details

I have two tables:

**Reservations Table (I separated them by date just for organizational purposes)**

```
Date             Name              Room Name     Seats Requested
01/1/2020        John              1             10
01/1/2020        Rebecca           3             30
01/1/2020        Haley             6             55

01/2/2020        David             1             10
01/2/2020        Rebecca           3             30
01/2/2020        Dasher            4             30

01/3/2020        Roger             4             40
01/3/2020        Doe               5             50
01/3/2020        Smith             3             30
```

**Room Table**

```
Name             Seats
1                10 
2                20
3                30
4                40
5                50
6                60
```

Each room will only appear ONCE for each date or won't appear at all. They are also on a "best fit" basis, as can see in the middle 3, both Rebecca and Dasher needed 30 seats, but since Rebecca got room 3, which is the best fitted room for her (30 seats) Dasher has to get the next "best" fit room for his 30 requested seats which is room 4 that has 40 seats available.

Now I have to "remove" a room from both tables: so the tables after like that would be something like this:

**Reservations Table (AFTER REMOVING ROOM 3)**

```
Date             Name              Room Name     Seats Requested
01/1/2020        John              1             10
01/1/2020        Rebecca                         30
01/1/2020        Haley             6             55

01/2/2020        David             1             10
01/2/2020        Rebecca                         30
01/2/2020        Dasher            4             30

01/3/2020        Roger             4             40
01/3/2020        Doe               5             50
01/3/2020        Smith                           30
```

**Room Table (AFTER REMOVING ROOM 3)**

```
Name             Seats
1                10 
2                20

4                40
5                50
6                60
```

So I want to write an SQL Query that will find the appropriate room that will be available to the people that got their room removed in the reservations table.

For example For date 1 (01/1/2020) Rebecca loses her room 3. Which means her next best room she can use is room 4.

For date 2 we see Rebecca again loses her room 3, except this time, room 4 is being used, which means her next best room she can use is room 5.

For date 3, Smith loses his room 3. But since room 4 and 5 is being used, his next available room he can use is room 6

### Expected output

My ideal output would be something like this:

```
Date             Name              Room Name     Seats Requested
01/1/2020        Rebecca           4             30
01/2/2020        Rebecca           5             30
01/3/2020        Smith             6             30
```

### Here's what I tried

I've already been able to remove the rooms as shown above, so that won't be necessary. Below is the SQL query I'm trying, but I'm getting syntax errors.

```
SELECT date,name,roomName,seatsRequested 
FROM reservations table1
where not exists (select 1
                  from Room table2
                  where table1.roomName = table2.Name)
AND MIN(table1.seatsRequested<=table2.seats)
GROUP BY date;
```

First I select the stuff I want to display. Then I want to find the rooms that don't exist in for a specific date.

Then I want to find the first room that will fit, so I use the "MIN()" function to do that, because for example, for date 1, if I didn't use the MIN() function, it would return two values: Room 4 and Room 5 because both of them are available for Rebecca to use. Using "MIN()" would hopefully only return Room 4.

Finally I group the query by the date so it applies to each date.

Just to clarify, I don't need any data inserted yet, just returned. If it's easier to simply just insert the data, then that is fine, but getting the returned stuff is really what I'm looking for.

I'm getting syntax errors (A plethora, things like GROUP BY isn't allowed, or like can't use MIN like that). And when I fix those errors I get nothing back. Not sure how to do this. Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you really are using.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *actually* using. SQL Server and MySQL and completed different products. *"I'm getting syntax errors. "* What are those errors?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Using Derby Databses through java, just added the tag, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Larnu A plethora, things like GROUP BY isn't allowed, or like can't use MIN like that.

Comment: Next is surely syntax error: `MIN(table1.seatsRequested<=table2.seats)`

Comment: Add them to your question, as a  [edit] @PSUChange alongside the statement that caused said error. Help the users here help you.

Comment: Your source data is strange. The Rooms table is date-independent. The Reservations table is date-dependent, and the room is re-used in different days. So the first step needed is in geteration a table where each room is combineв with each date mentioned in reservations. This table and Reservations must be a source for processing, and you'll "remove" not a romm but a pair (room-date). This will be logical.

Comment: @Larnu will do,

Comment: @Akina does this mean SQL does not provide the functionality to get my desired output?

Comment: SQL provides enough functionality. But it cannot provide the logic - this is YOUR task.

Comment: @Akina My logic is bad right?

Comment: Each person will reserve a room separately. For example, Jim wants to reserve a room with 25+ seats for 01/1/2020. Rooms 1,3,6 are already reserved, room 2 does not match, so rooms 4 and 5 are matching and available, and room 4 must be shown/reserved for him. You do not need to investigate the reservations for another dates. Jim simply enters "01/1/2020" and "25 places" and receives "room 4". That's all. Is it?

Comment: @Akina yes, that's right. I was using java for my inputs (user inputs a date and how many seats they want) and I used that input to write an SQL query to INSERT that data into the reservations table*. Then the user selects a room to delete and that's where I am at now it removed data from the table with SQL. now I just need SQL to return me the values for each one and then I'll use java to "reassign" them to open rooms. and if there are no open rooms, I simply just put them into a different table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each person will reserve a room separately. For example, Jim wants to reserve a room with 25+ seats for 01/1/2020. Rooms 1,3,6 are already reserved, room 2 does not match, so rooms 4 and 5 are matching and available, and room 4 must be shown/reserved for him. You do not need to investigate the reservations for another dates. Jim simply enters "01/1/2020" and "25 places" and receives "room 4". That's all. Is it? – Akina

> @Akina yes, that's right. I was using java for my inputs and removal. now I just need SQL to return me the values for each one and then I'll use java to insert them. but if SQL has the functionality perhaps I don't need to use JAVA at all. – PSU Change

```
SELECT Room.Name 
FROM Room 
LEFT JOIN Reservation ON Room.Name = Reservation.RoomName
                     AND Reservation.Date = {entered date}
WHERE Reservation.RoomName IS NULL
  AND Room.Seats >= {entered amount}
ORDER BY Room.Seats ASC LIMIT 1
```

If (in current data state) Jim enters `01/1/2020` as date and `25` as amount then the query will return `4`. If Jim agreed then this room is reserved and according row is inserted into Reservations. If he not agreed he may alter the amount and/or date and maybe receive another room or refuse to reserve a room at all.

Also you may remove `LIMIT 1` - in such case Jim will see 2 variants for reservation, rooms `4` and `5`. He'll select one of them by some reasons (for example, reservation price may influence), and according info will be added into the table.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant "up to that point" that's what is happening. I'm at the point where a user selects a "room" to remove, and my SQL will readjust the tables according to the rooms removed. Thank you for this anyway I'll just post a new question since the miscommunication is my fault. I already can insert values appropriately into my reservations table. I just need to readjust my tables after a room gets removed.

Comment: Hmmm . . . I can't point to the exact flaw, but I don't think this fully solves the problem.  I'm pretty sure the solution requires a recursive CTE, so once one room is reassigned, the previously assigned room can be assigned to someone else.

Comment: @GordonLinoff *once one room is reassigned, the previously assigned room can be assigned to someone else.* I think that re-assign and assign this room to somebody else are two independent processes. Between them there is some data state. But looking on this state there is no difference what operations were performed before. Reassigning either updates reservation row or deletes it but inserts another one. I do not see why recursion may be needed. Except the choice when such reservations/reassignings are the content of some input table, and they must be performed as a batch.